# Estou criando um sistema de comentário em PHP, mas na conclusão do trabalho me deparei com o seguinte erro:

Tags: php

Código:

```html
<?php include "connection.php"; ?>

<?php
$nome=$_POST['nome'];
$comentario=$_POST['comentario'];
?>

<?php 
$insert = "INSERT INTO comentarios_tb nome, comentario"
VALUES('$nome', '$comentario')";
$sql = mysqli_master_query($insert);
echo "<center><h3>Obrigado, seu comentário foi enviado!</center>";
?>
```

Erro de análise:

> erro de sintaxe, 'VALORES' inesperados (T_STRING) em C: \ wamp64 \ www
>   \ comentarios \ inserir comentário.php na linha 10

Comment: Há um erro na linha da variável $insert, o ideal seria você postar o código por texto aqui. Recomendo você editar a pergunta e acrescentar o código de maneira que possamos copiar e ti ajudar!

Comment: Retira as ultimas aspas da linha do insert

Comment: ok irei alterar a minha publicação

Answer (score 2):

A sua instrução de `insert` ficou com uma aspa `"` a mais no meio. Como está dividida em duas linhas fica mais difícil de ver.

Falta também `(` e `)` entre os campos que estão a ser inseridos, o `nome, comentario`.

Deveria estar assim:

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO comentarios_tb (nome, comentario)  VALUES('$nome', '$comentario')";
//------------------------------------------------------^ sem " aqui porque já está ----^ aqui
```

Na linha da *query* falta a conexão e devia ser:

```
$sql = mysqli_master_query($conn, $insert);
//--------------------------^ conexão agora aqui
```

Deve também considerar não utilizar [`mysqli_master_query`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysqli-master-query.php) pois foi marcada como obsoleta e foi removida no PHP 5.3.0.

Answer (score -2):

Na linha:

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO comentarios_tb nome, comentario"
```

Falta um `;`.